# Remove first and last instance of a character from a string?

Tags: c++

I assume the following doesn't compile because I am mixing forward and reverse iterators. Why can't I mix them like this? How can I get it to work? I want to remove the first and last quote of the string, but leave any internal quotes present.

```
temp.assign(find(value.begin(), value.end(), '\"'), find(value.rbegin(), value.rend(), '\"'));
```

I cannot even do this. What is the point of reverse iterators?

```
value.erase(find(value.begin(), value.end(), '\"'));
value.erase(find(value.rbegin(), value.rend(), '\"'));
```

Comment: Can you just make a copy `std::string stripped( str.begin() + 1, str.end() - 1)` and assert or execute only if begin and end are valid and contains quotes

Comment: The quotation marks might not be exactly the first or last character, sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: @user814628 Not to mention what would happen if you passed the function an empty string.

Comment: Note that `assign(it1, it2)` will discard everything up to `it1` and everything beginning at `it2` and onwards. If you only want to remove characters at `it1` and `it2`, this is not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assign function (regardless of the type of `temp`) requires 
two iterators of the same type.  A reverse iterator doesn't have
the same type as a normal iterator.  You can get at the
underlying normal iterator using the `base()` function on the
reverse iterator, but be careful; it is one behind the position the
reverse iterator is pointing to.  For example, if you write

```
temp.assign( find( value.begin(), value.end(), '\"' ),
             find( value.rbegin(), value.rend(), '\"').base() );
```

, the trailing `'"'` will be part of the resulting string.

This particular behavior is often what you want when you're
using the results as a beginning iterator:

```
std::string( std::find( fn.rbegin(), fn.rend(), '.' ), fn.end() )
```

, for example, will give you all of the text *after* the last
`'.'`.  When using the results of a find with reverse iterators
as the end criteron, you'll usually need to save it in
a variable, and "correct" it in some way.

Finally, you should be extremely cautious about using the
results of two finds to define a range, like you do above.  If
there's no `'"'` in your text, for example, you'll end up with
the equivalent of:

```
temp.assign( value.end(), value.begin() );
```

, which isn't going to work.

### EDIT:

As an example, if you don't want the `'"'` characters, I think the
following should work:

```
//  Returns an empty string if there are not two " chars.
std::string
extractQuoted( std::string const& original )
{
    //  end points to one after the last '"', or begin() if no '"'.
    std::string::const_iterator end
        = std::find( original.rbegin(), original.rend(), '"' ).base();
    if ( end != original.begin() ) {
        -- end;    // Since we don't want the '"' in the final string
    }
    return std::string( std::find( original.begin(), end, '"' ), end );
}
```

(It's off the top of my head, so no guarantees, but it should
get you started in the right direction.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use reverse_itertators, call .base() on them to the underlying iterator type. e.g.

```
value.erase(find(value.begin(), value.end(), '\"'));
value.erase(find(value.rbegin(), value.rend(), '\"').base());
```

might do the trick.

Comment: Or it might not.  I rather suspect that he doesn't want either of the `'"'` in the final string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that erase expects a forward iterator, not a reverse iterator.  As others have pointed out you can just use .base() on the result of find to convert them.

You could also use find_end instead.

Comment: Using a reverse iterator to find the _last_ occurance of something is perfectly valid and idiomatic.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah I think you are right, I didn't know about .base().  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
value.erase(0, value.find('\"') + 1);
value.erase(value.rfind('\"'), value.size());
```

Assuming the string will always contain atleast two `"`s

Comment: First, that's a dangerous assumption.  Second, your code will only erase the `'"'` characters; judging from his original code, he wanted to erase the characters before the first `'"'` and after the last `'"'` as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
void stripLeadingAndTrailingQuotes(std::string& s) {
    if (s[0] == '\"')
        s.erase(0, 1);
    size_t last = s.length() - 1;
    if (s[last] == '\"')
        s.erase(last, 1);
}
```

Iterators are valid but I think the above is a lot more readable.